# Loging in to Meta Stack Overflow fails

Tags: support, meta, login

My login that works everywhere on other Stack Exchange sites, doesn't work on Meta Stack Overflow. What could possibly go wrong? I login to multiple sites on Stack Exchange using same credentials without any issue at all.

(Note: I asked this question on Stack Overflow as I was unable to login. I believe there is a bug causing it, details in comments)

Comment: Yeah, but where else is he going to ask about a problem with Meta?   What credentials are you using?   (OpenID?   Stack Exchange?)

Comment: Ironically, it belongs on meta

Comment: FranciscoCorrales! Can you please tell where can I seek help otherwise, I will be thankful to you

@GreenAsJade I am using StackExchange credentials. It doesn't even give an error message on Meta SO, just stays there like i didn't even press anything. I tried password recovery, and it sent me an email saying that I don't have an account on meta. When I tried creating one, it says email in use. This is confusing, and may be sort of bug.

Comment: In the short term, try different creds (google or something else).   Then you can get on there and ask them :)

Comment: With google account attempt, this is the response.

Suspicious request
Sorry, your request could not be completed because it looked suspicious. If you meant to perform an action on Meta Stack Overflow, please return to the previous page and try again.

Comment: Well thanks @GreenAsJade It worked!!! attempted 2 times, and signed in using google. Seems like Meta SO needs to be linked to gmail separately. I linked and now can login to Meta. I appreciate your time :)